# flexslider carousel issue with the href="stuff.php#codeword"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hyperlink, slider

i have the following code fot a carousel slider

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide3.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide4.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
  <img src="slide1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide3.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="slide4.jpg" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

i'm using the carousel to show some products (freezers, fridges and stuff), but there are some pages that leads to that carousel and i want it to take you to a specific slide of the carousel, i've ried using the href="products-page.php#freezer" and it takes me to the slide, but the carousel get's broken and stuff goes to hell

any idea of what can i do to fix that or what code can i use to accomplish it?

Comment: how do you implement your slider/carousel? is a custom implementation or do you use some plugin?

Comment: i'm using this one http://flexslider.woothemes.com/